# UserControl inside RadGridView Child Row - Telerik Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

Is there any way to load a User Control inside RadGridView Child row?
I also need to pass a value to user control on expanding the row.

Here is an image (It is made by ASP not winforms)

[image]

as you can see there is something similar to user control in the child row in which users can edit values in a better view.

How to achieve such a thing with RadGridView?

Comment: I think you are searching for `RowDetailsTemplate`. I have used that thing in silverlight, WPF and UWP, however, I didn't find anything like this for winforms. You can check the link of Telerik=> [Link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radgridview-with-row-details)